# How do I add this intro page to my app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wanting to include the nice_intro package (https://pub.dev/packages/nice_intro into my app that uses kfdrawer (https://pub.dev/packages/kf_drawer) for it's main navigation. The app shows no errors and compiles, but I lose connection to the device (emulator) as soon as it runs every time. Obviously I've done something wrong.

Here is the main page (kfdrawer)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:kf_drawer/kf_drawer.dart';
//import 'package:sliding_drawer/screens/calendar_page.dart';

//import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/clusters_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/help_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/map_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/places_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/safety_info_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/screens/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/utils/class_builder.dart';

import 'package:manchestermaps/locale/locales.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/theme.dart' as Theme;

void main() {
  ClassBuilder.registerClasses();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
        AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        // Built-in localization of basic text for Material screens
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', ''),
        Locale('fr', ''),
        Locale('ar', ''),
        Locale('de', ''),
        Locale('es', ''),
        Locale('hi', ''),
        Locale('zh', ''),
        Locale('ja', '')
      ],
      theme: Theme.uniThemeData,
      home: MainWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MainWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MainWidgetState createState() => _MainWidgetState();
}

class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  KFDrawerController _drawerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _drawerController = KFDrawerController(
      initialPage: ClassBuilder.fromString('IntroPage'),
      items: [
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).mainMenuCampusMap,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.white,
            semanticLabel: 'Display Menu',
          ),
          page: MapPage(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).drawerPCClusters,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.computer, color: Colors.white),
          page: ClustersPage(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).mainMenuMyPlaces,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.place, color: Colors.white),
          page: PlacesPage(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).mainMenuSafetyInfo,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike, color: Colors.white),
          page: SafetyInfoPage(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).mainMenuSettings,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
          page: SettingsPage(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: KFDrawer(
//        borderRadius: 0.0,
//        shadowBorderRadius: 0.0,
//        menuPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
//        scrollable: true,
        controller: _drawerController,
        header: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            child: ExcludeSemantics(
              excluding: true,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/imgs/generic/colourLogo.png',
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        footer: KFDrawerItem(
          text: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).mainMenuHelp,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.help_outline,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return HelpPage();
              },
            ));
          },
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            stops: [0.1, 0.7, 1.0],
            colors: [
              Theme.UniColour.secondary[300],
              Theme.UniColour.primary[300],
              Theme.UniColour.primary[700]
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Intro Page code (This is my problem page)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kf_drawer/kf_drawer.dart';
import 'package:manchestermaps/locale/locales.dart';
import 'package:nice_intro/intro_screen.dart';
import 'package:nice_intro/intro_screens.dart';

import 'package:manchestermaps/theme.dart' as Theme;

class IntroPage extends KFDrawerContent {
  @override
  _IntroWidgetState createState() => _IntroWidgetState();
}

class IntroWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  IntroWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _IntroWidgetState createState() => _IntroWidgetState();
}

class _IntroWidgetState extends State<IntroPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _fontSize = 14.0;
  final double _baseFontSize = 14.0;
  double _fontScale = 1.0;
  double _baseFontScale = 1.0;
  double _maxScale = 2.2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails caleStartDetails) {
        _baseFontScale = _fontScale;
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails scaleUpdateDetails) {
        setState(() {
          _fontScale =
              (_baseFontScale * scaleUpdateDetails.scale).clamp(1.0, _maxScale);
          _fontSize = _fontScale * _baseFontSize;
        });
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        minimum: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0),
        child: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                      child: Material(
                        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 32.0,
                            semanticLabel: 'Display Main Menu',
                          ),
                          onPressed: widget.onMenuPressed,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Press for Main Menu',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: _introduction(context),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@override
Widget _introduction(BuildContext context) {
  var screens = IntroScreens(
    onDone: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => NextPage(),
      ),
    ),
    onSkip: () => print('Skipping the intro slides'),
    footerBgColor: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
    activeDotColor: Colors.white,
    footerRadius: 18.0,
//      indicatorType: IndicatorType.CIRCLE,
    slides: [
      IntroScreen(
        title: 'Search',
        imageAsset: 'assets/imgs/intro/1.png',
        description: 'Quickly find all your messages',
        headerBgColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      IntroScreen(
        title: 'Focused Inbox',
        headerBgColor: Colors.white,
        imageAsset: 'assets/imgs/intro/2.png',
        description: "We've put your most important, actionable emails here",
      ),
      IntroScreen(
        title: 'Social',
        headerBgColor: Colors.white,
        imageAsset: 'assets/imgs/intro/3.png',
        description: "Keep talking with your mates",
      ),
    ],
  );

  return screens;
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

I have been fighting for 3 years to be allowed to develop this and finally word is getting out. It is gaining some momentum and management are asking for a progress report and a demo of it. I do have something to show them, but this would be a nice addition, which shows a bit of professionalism in my thinking.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Were you able to work something out? I'm stuck with the same issue!

Comment: I did get this working, but I can't get to my code atm. With Covid, I have been working from home and the machine I was remoting into now has the Blue Screen Of Death, due to a power shutoff in the building I worked in. I have reported this and I now have to wait until they have restored everything. 

It's been a while since I worked on this project, so I can't remember fully. As soon as I get the code back, I'll update. I'll bookmark this page, but please keep reminding me, as I have no timeframe of when the machine will be restored, but I have mentioned it is urgent.